# resouce not found but it's in its place

Tags: android

My reports provide me this error but I can't understand how is it possible?

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.aviascanner.aviascanner/net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.GetCitiesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2753)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3905)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2600(ActivityThread.java:129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2121)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
            at net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.GetCitiesActivity.onCreate(GetCitiesActivity.java:115)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2717)
            ... 12 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:51)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
            ... 25 more
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/selector_edittext.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200c4
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1725)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1901)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:440)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:55)
            ... 29 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:349)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:265)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:796)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:737)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1722)
            ... 33 more
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
            at net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.GetCitiesActivity.onCreate(GetCitiesActivity.java:115)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2717)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3905)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2600(ActivityThread.java:129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2121)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:51)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
            ... 25 more
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/selector_edittext.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200c4
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1725)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1901)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:440)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:55)
            ... 29 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:349)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:265)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:796)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:737)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1722)
            ... 33 more
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:51)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
            at net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.GetCitiesActivity.onCreate(GetCitiesActivity.java:115)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2717)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3905)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2600(ActivityThread.java:129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2121)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/selector_edittext.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200c4
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1725)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1901)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:440)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:55)
            ... 29 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:349)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:265)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:796)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:737)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1722)
            ... 33 more
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/selector_edittext.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200c4
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1725)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1901)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:440)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:55)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:51)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
            at net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.GetCitiesActivity.onCreate(GetCitiesActivity.java:115)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2717)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3905)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2600(ActivityThread.java:129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2121)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:349)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:265)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:796)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:737)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1722)
            ... 33 more
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:349)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:265)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:796)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:737)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1722)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1901)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:440)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:55)
            at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:51)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:853)
            at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:262)
            at net.aviascanner.aviascanner.ui.activities.GetCitiesActivity.onCreate(GetCitiesActivity.java:115)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2717)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3905)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2600(ActivityThread.java:129)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2121)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Something is wrong in your xml files somewhere.

Comment: Please post the XML file you are using to inflate your ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: @Erol xml of activity?

Comment: The layout you are setting at GetCitiesActivity.onCreate().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this error in my application also. In my application I solved my problem by making the copies of the drawables in all the folders of the drawables i.e. drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi. This works correctly in my application. Hope this will solve your problem if u have not kept the drawables into all the provided drawable folders.

Comment: yes, I have resources only xhdpi folder. But other sizes looks pretty good. Is there possible workarounds? I.e. if I move resources to drawable forlder?

Comment: ya just copy all the drawables from xhdpi folder to all other drawable folders.

Comment: if I copy all the drawables to all other drawable folders the size of my apk file will increase. I mean copy **drawable-xhdpi** to **drawable**.

Comment: you can do it but sometimes it increases the memory consumption(heap size) in case of xhdpi mobiles for example samsung galaxy note. You can put the conflicting drawables to all the folders. It will work correctly in the drawable folder.(except the out of memory exception).

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal - 
Can you expand on the 'increases the memory consumption' ? Does having PNG only in 'drawable' folder uses more memory that having a copy of the same PNG in all drawable-XXX folders?

Comment: I researched on it and found that by keeping the images in drawable folder take much memory. I think the reason is that re-sizing of images according to the resolution of the phone.