# Android: NullPointerException happened in DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild

Tags: android, android-layout

First, this crash happened only few times, randomly. And from the crash log, it should not a OOM problem for i cannot see any clue about "OutOfMemoryError". Neither it is resource not found because it should throw Resources$NotFoundException. The crashlog is as below (the root exception)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:349)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:265)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:796)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:737)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1722)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1834)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:614)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at bes.a(VideoDetailFragement.java:332)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.b(Fragment.java:1460)
at u.a(FragmentManager.java:911)
at u.a(FragmentManager.java:1088)
at h.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at u.e(FragmentManager.java:1444)
at n.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3800)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2710)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2753)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:129)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2107)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I checked the layout file, and I'm sure the drawables are right there, while only in xhdpi folder. From the following link
[resouce not found but it's in its place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394499/resouce-not-found-but-its-in-its-place)

It gives the resolution that

> In my application I solved my problem by making the copies of the
>   drawables in all the folders of the drawables i.e. drawable-ldpi,
>   drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi

I didn't try, but, if so, then why? From the [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), it says

> Screen pixel density is the one qualifier that is not eliminated due to a contradiction. Even though the screen density of the device is hdpi, drawable-port-ldpi/ is not eliminated because every screen density is considered to be a match at this point

So in my opinion, in a low dpi device, it should find a drawable from the xhdpi one and scale it down to a appropriate size. So i dont know why it sometimes throws such exception.

-------------------------------------UPDATE--------------------------

As request, i post the another layout file and the crash log, which also the same problem..
XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/advert_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/advert_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/advert_close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/advert_img"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/advert_img"
    android:paddingBottom="9dp"
    android:paddingLeft="9dp"
    android:paddingRight="9dp"
    android:paddingTop="9dp"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/advert_close_img"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/advert_close" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/advert_img"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/advert_img"
    android:paddingBottom="38dp"
    android:paddingLeft="53dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/advert_goto"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/advert_goto_bt_selector"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the drawable advert_goto_bt_selector is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/advert_goto_btn_press" />
   <item  android:drawable="@drawable/advert_goto_btn" />
</selector>
```

I am quite sure the advert_goto_btn_press.png and advert_goto_btn.png， advert_close exist in the xhdpi in the apk file

Crash log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.addChild(DrawableContainer.java:349)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.addStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:265)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:796)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:737)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1722)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:176)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:172)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at com.xxxx.video.ui.widget.AdvertView.a(AdvertView.java:111)
at com.xxxx.video.ui.widget.AdvertView.<init>(AdvertView.java:89)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:203)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1666)
at com.xxxx.video.player.PlayerActivity.onCreate(PlayerActivity.java:236)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2701)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2753)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:129)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2107)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the Java code is quite simple, it is inflating the layout file.

Comment: can you post the java code too..

Comment: post your selector xml file

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is caused by the density-specific drawables? Maybe it is caused by other config-specific drawables.

Comment: i cannot get any clue about other config for the resources are classified only in "dpi" mode. For drawables, i have drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-nodpi and drawable-xhdpi, no orientation or localization or other config.

Comment: have you found any solution ?